# Having a list in a VBScript Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

I want to build a Dictionary. But the value should be a list of strings. In C# this would be

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Can I do this somehow in VBS? Or maybe with a workaround? Later I want to iterate over that dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array, E.g.

```
dict.add "pizza", array("cheese", "tomato", "ham")

for each x in dict("pizza")
    msgbox x
next
```

Comment: I usually use an ArrayList `set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`